# using enum as semantic type in Bison C++

Tags: c++, bison

How can I use an enum as type as shown below

```
%type <order_direction> ordering_direction opt_ordering_direction
```

when i have defined order_direction in a separate header file as

```
enum enum_order : int { ORDER_NOT_RELEVANT = 1, ORDER_ASC, ORDER_DESC };
enum_order order_direction;
```

which i include in the Bison file? When i try to link the object files i get this error:

```
error: ‘order_direction’ is not a type
 5091 |       basic_symbol (typename Base::kind_type t, order_direction&& v, location_type&& l)
```

I also use the following definitions in my .y file

```
%define api.token.constructor
%define api.value.type variant
%define parse.assert
```

Comment: The error message should be quite clear: To set a type you need to use an actual *type*. For example `enum_order` is a type.

Comment: Did you mean to make a type alias (`typedef enum_order order_direction;` or `using order_direction = enum_order;`)?

Comment: using ```enum_order``` instead of ```order_direction``` solves the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `enum_direction` is an **enumerator** and not an *enumaration type*. This means `enum_direction` cannot be used as a type.

To solve this, you must use a **type** where a type is required. This means you can use `enum_order` as the type of the function parameter instead of `enum_direction`( as the former is a type).